# SQL query to print formated string

Tags: sql

I would like to "print" an input name using a query in the following format:

Suppose my input string is `"Sujeet Kumar Panda"` then I should get `"s.k.panda"`.

Comment: Read into `Substring` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx | http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_function_substring.php

Comment: SQL and databases are great for **storing, searching and retrieving** data. Most SQL dialects aren't quite as powerful when it comes to text processing - that's better done in your front-end code, whether that by Ruby, Java, PHP, or C# or whatever else.....

Answer (score 0):

for SQL statement considering that `FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME` in the DATABASE..

```
substr(FIRST_NAME,1,1) + '.' + substr(MIDDLE_NAME) + '.' + LAST_NAME
```

so `substr(FIRST_NAME,1,1)` would print 's' of sujeet..

also, in case there is no MIDDLE_NAME for some names, you need to use DECODE function to rectify this..

also, check if USER has no last name also..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select substring('Sujeet Kumar Panda',1,1) + '.' 
    + substring('Sujeet Kumar Panda',(CHARINDEX ( '_','Sujeet Kumar Panda')+1),1) + '.' 
    + substring(substring('Sujeet Kumar Panda',(CHARINDEX ( ' ','Sujeet Kumar Panda')+1),20), charindex(' ',substring('Sujeet Kumar Panda',(CHARINDEX ( ' ','Sujeet Kumar Panda')+1),20)),20)
```